# Simplify similar Object Literal in javascript code

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri

Is there any way to simplify this code, I appreciate any ideas.
in lyerDefs I have the same value for all objects from 1 to 11.

```
spider = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
    url:API,
    layers:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
    layerDefs:{ // how to simplify following code?

      1:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      2:  "Site_id ='" + activeSiteId +"'",
      3:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      4:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      5:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      6:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      7:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      8:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      9:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      10:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'",
      11:  "Site_id ='"+ activeSiteId +"'"

    }
  } );
```

Comment: What is the broader context of this? Because you could just use a loop to generate this but it might be possible to eliminate the need for the repeat altogether if we know *why* this is here.

Comment: `layerDefs: generateDefs(11 /* making an assumption */)`, then it's only about what is in the "generateDefs" function. As noted, a simple loop would suffice in this case.. although the extent of data-duplication feels off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by simplifying it.  I'm assuming that you don't want to repeat the "Site_id = '" + activeSiteId +"'" string eleven times.  If that's all, then this should do:

```
var layers = [];
var layerDefs = {};
for(i = 1; i < 12; i++) {
  layers.push(i);
  layerDefs[i] = "Site_id = '" + activeSiteId + "'";
}
spider = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
  url:API,
  layers: layers,
  layerDefs: layerDefs
});
```

Comment: Yes that solved the repetition of "Site_id = '" + activeSiteId +"'"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will generate layers and layerDefs. Below example uses the `.reduce` method.

```
function generateLayersAndDefs(layers) {
  return {
    layers: layers,
    layerDefs: layers.reduce(function(final, current) {
      final[current] = "Site_id ='" + current + "'"
      return final;
    }, {})
  };
}

spider = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer(
  Object.assign(
    {
      url:API
    },
    generateLayersAndDefs([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
  )
);
```